# Flat buffers : Object serialization must not be nested

Tags: flatbuffers

```
        FlatBufferBuilder fbb = new FlatBufferBuilder(1024);

        String directory = "/Users/samarnath/RmsOne/CreateFlatBuffer/src/com/rms/objects/resources";
        File [] policyfiles = ReturnFilesWithPattern(directory, "singlecoverriskpolicy");

        for (File file: policyfiles)
        {

            Long StructureId = 0L;
            int insurer = 0;
            int insured = 0;
            int UnderWriter = 0;
            int inception = 0;
            int Expiration = 0;
            int ExternalID = 0;
            Long SubjectId =0L;
            int SubjectName = 0;
            int SubjectStructureName = 0;
            int Share = 0;
            Double blanketLimit = 0.0;
            Double attachment = 0.0;
            int causeofLoss = 0;
            int maxDeductible = 0;
            int attachmentCurrency = 0;
            int offset= 0;
            int deductibleCurrencyOffset = 0;
            int createOffset =0;
            int blanketLimitCurrency = 0;


            String folderName = "nfs://dev-spark-share.lab.rmsonecloud.net/mnt/data/UserData/import/outputfiles/Job_5/SmokeTest_2M/eufl_only_client4_2_edm__20151203-134544__24/contract/";
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
            List<String> actualLines = lines.subList(1, lines.size());

            for (String line:actualLines)
            {
                String [] riskitems = line.split("~");

                SingleCoverRiskPolicy.startSingleCoverRiskPolicy(fbb);
                Long Id  = Long.parseLong(riskitems[0]);
                int policyName = fbb.createString(riskitems[1]);
```

After the above line i get an error saying Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: FlatBuffers: object serialization must not be nested.I get an error in fbb.createString.

The code is simple and i cant figure out whats wrong here

Comment: Apparently your code snippet is not complete

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/md__java_usage.html): "Everything else (other tables, strings, vectors) MUST be created before the start of the table they are referenced in."

So move `int policyName = fbb.createString(riskitems[1])` and any other strings/vectors/tables you reference in `SingleCoverRiskPolicy` to before `startSingleCoverRiskPolicy`.